# Log of stored procedure parameters?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, logging, stored-procedures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tracing a stored procedure’s parameters handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279470/tracing-a-stored-procedures-parameters-handling)

Is there any out-of-the-box functionality within SQL Server 2008 that will allow me to see a log of procedures executed, and the parameters passed?

We have a stored procedure whose return is used to determine if a user can log in to our application or not, and the stored procedure is returning some unexpected results. I'm trying to troubleshoot by seeing if the user ID is getting garbled as it's passed to the stored procedure, but I can't quite seem to find where I could go to check that.

Does such a log/viewer exist?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL Trace, or SQL profiler, which is essentially a GUI for the same tool.

Details of SQL Trace here msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191006(v=sql.105).aspx

Profiler here msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Pete has the right answer if you need to track everything that is run, but if you can modify the procedures yourself you can add logging functionality (something like inserting to a table with the relevant details) directly to the procedure.  This avoids the potentially large performance impact of the profiler.